# Найти предел представимых значений для целочисленных типов данных С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    short a;
    a = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        a += 1;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}
```

Как Экспериментальным путем написать алгоритм для целочисленных типов данных (только арифметические операторы) выводящий такое число, что с прибавлением или вычитанием единицы получится Переход от верхней границы к нижней???

Comment: Для беззнакового типа: `unsigned int a = -1;`. Для знакового типа: `int a = (unsigned int)-1 / 2;`. Но вообще говоря переполнение знакового целого вызывает неопределённое поведение, а не переход от верхней границы к нижней.

Comment: Еще добавлю, что в С++ не предусмотрено арифметических операций для типа short. В примере происходит неявное преобразование в int и обратно.

Comment: Если для платформ x86/x64, то `unsigned int a = 0xffffffff` (бесзнаковое целое), `int a = 0x7fffffff` (знаковое целое). Для 16-битных целых в половину меньше разрядов: `unsigned short a = 0xffff`, `short a = 0x7fff` Хотя это, конечно, не алгоритм, а непосредственные значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int i = -1;

    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(i) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]